# Image proportional to screen resolution - think JS is knocking it out

Tags: javascript

I'm sure one of you lot there can help with this. I'm new to the web game and have been stumped on a particular part of my own website design, currently found at build.tombritton.me

I would like the image on div #one and the image slider to display at full size of the viewer's browser - no matter what resolution their display may be.

I'm sure the Javascript i have linked to the html is knocking out my css or controlling it at least. However, I understand little to no JS and moderate CSS and HTML understanding.

Please let me know what code you require me to upload so you can browse and hope that you can assist me in the very near future.

Thank you guys so much in advance, this would be a great help as I cannot seem to progress any further.

TomB

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

To your CSS. The browser is adding some default padding.

Comment: Thanks that particular issue has been resolved. However, my last parallax scroll at build.tombritton.me isnt working quite right. Whenever I bring in the browser width, the image doesnt extend to the display height. Any ideas? 100% height will knock out the image slider.

Comment: @TomB - I don't know what `whenever i bring in the browser width` means.